# X5687 vs X5690 CPUs for a SQL 2008 R2 Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the choice between:

2 x X5687 (Intel® Xeon® Processor X5687 - QuadCore
(12M Cache, 3.60 GHz, 6.40 GT/s Intel® QPI)

or 
2 x X5690 (Intel® Xeon® Processor X5690 - SixCore
(12M Cache, 3.46 GHz, 6.40 GT/s Intel® QPI)

for a new DB Server (SQL 2008 R2 64bit), my personal preference is X5690, are there reasons that would speak against going for a SixCore CPU vs. a QuadCore CPU ?

Comment: I heard that the cache might be an issue, since it is shared by more cores and therefore can impact the performance of SQL Server in a negative way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2008R2, I'd take the extra cores every time.

If the server might be upgraded to Denali/2012 on release you may need to factor in the switch from per socket to per core licensing. @MrDenny summarised this well in [SQL Server 2012 Licensing Changes](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/sql-server-2012-licensing-changes/).

Answer (score 1):

Obviously from a hardware perspective, I'd go with the X5690.  Just make sure to check with the licensing agreement you have with Microsoft.  I thought I remembered reading somewhere that there's a SQL Server 2008 licensing option that requires you to have enough licenses on a per-core basis.

As long as you don't have that, I'd say go with the X5690.  If your agreement does mandate licensing on a per-core basis, then check and see if two more cores justifies the increase in cost.

Comment: A little mistake about licensing - it is per socket, not per core, so - the multicore rules! My own choice - 4x6 core cpu

Comment: Thanks Oleg!  I couldn't remember if core-licensing affected 2008 or 2012.  But it helps to be conscious about that.